# JQuery - Animation scrollTop

Tags: jquery, html

I have two buttons and 2 hidden parts related to these buttons.
When a button is clicked, it's related part will show up and the document will scroll to the top.

Problem: The part is shown, but doesn't move to the top.

Please help. Thanks!

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rb0z2htp/)

**HTML**

```
<div style="border:1px solid black;width:100px;height:250px;overflow:auto">
This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.
</div>
<a data-target="one">First Button</a>
<a data-target="two">Second Button</a>

<hr>
<div class="hide" id="one">First Element</div>
<hr>
<div class="hide" id="two">Second Element</a>
<hr>
```

**JS**

```
$("a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var target = $(this).data("target");
    $('#' + target).show().animate({
        scrollTop: "0px"
    }, 800);
});
```

Comment: The item move to top or document (browser) move to the top? Or the element is a text box that scrolls to the top line? Btw in all cases, your code and CSS is all wrong

Comment: The items (First Element, Second Element) will move to the top after we click on First or Second botton.

Comment: Why not just move them upper in HTML markup? You need to be animated?

Comment: Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/rb0z2htp/1/

Comment: The table will be a long one and when I scroll down, I see First and Second buttons.  After I click one one of the buttons, if I don't move First Element to the top, it will show, but not visible. Thing is the table need to move up and inviable so that the elements (they will be long, too) will show on the top

Comment: I don't get it (sorry it's my fault). Maybe this help `$('#' + target).show(); $(document).animate({ scrollTop: "0px" }, 800);`. Replcae this line of code with your codes after `var target`

Comment: Thanks, Colin Cline so much for help.  Yes, it works so well!  How can I vote for your answer?  Please let me know.

Comment: I posted the solution as an answer. You can vote there and accept it as your answer. Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to scroll to the top, you must use this js code and it's better to not use selectors like `a` in this way because it will force js to trigger our function for every single `a` tag. Modify it in this way `$("a[data-target]")`

```
$("a[data-target]").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var target = $(this).data("target");
    $('#' + target).show();
    $(document).animate({ scrollTop: "0px" }, 800);
});
```

Or for a better result, you can make it Asynchronous:

```
$("a[data-target]").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var target = $(this).data("target");
    $('#' + target).show("slow", function(){
        $(document).animate({ scrollTop: "0px" }, 800);
    });
});
```